# Messenger InstantGames - web request works fine on Messenger webpage, but fails when played through Messenger mobile app

Tags: android, ios, facebook-messenger, facebook-instant-games

I have a game written in TypeScript uploaded into Facebook Instant Games. I have a super simple call to obtain real `timestamp` from my own server.

I managed to get it working after uploading a build into InstantGames and after facing issues with CORS. I get proper response with `status 200`.

However, there is an issue with the same request, but from InstantGame played through Messenger app, both on iOS and android. I tried to put as match logs as possible, with no reasonable answer.

I am creating `XMLHttpRequest()`, when the game is started on desktop browser I finally get:

`xhr.readyState == 4` and `xhr.status == 200`.

I am using `https` url.

On mobile Messenger, I get only `xhr.readyState == 4` and **`xhr.status == 0`**.

I also tried with moving from `XMLHttpRequest()` into `fetch()`, same behavior - on desktop browser it works fine, on mobile I get:

`I/chromium(22226): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch"`

Server code:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my-app-id.apps.fbsbx.com');
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->getTimestamp();
?>
```

Any ideas why is it failing when played by mobile Messenger app and how to fix it properly?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the exact same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved this issue some months ago, so I'm sharing an answer with you.

The clue was, that I was testing this on `Opera` browser (on desktop), when I finally tested it on `Chrome`, then I had same errors like on mobile `Messenger` which uses `Chromium`.

The problem was, that my own server didn't have a proper own certificate for this exact domain. `Chrome` was forcing use of `https` and then it was failing because of a certificate owned by hosting, pointing to a hostserver domain instead of my own.

Usage of my own certificate solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you hit, but the messenger apps don't like HTTP/2.  Lost several hours of my life on figuring that out.